# Getting quarter according to date in date column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find the quarter in which a particular date comes.

currently I am doing this with an `if /else` structure like below:

```
select if(month(s_date) < 4,Q1,if(month(s_date) >3 && month(s_date) < 7,Q2,.....)
```

Am I doing this right or there is another simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to calculate it manually . Mysql already have function `QUARTER()` which returns quarter in which particular date comes

Below will make it simple :

```
SELECT QUARTER(s_date) as quarter FROM tablename
```